# How to drag org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer android?

Tags: android, surfaceview, apprtc, videocall

This is layout of videocall in my app. I use webrtc library. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/akK7p.jpg

I want to drag SurfaceViewRenderer which on right&top to any where in screen device.So how can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: I change SurfaceViewRenderer to TextureViewRenderer then use custom drag to move video. It's work ok.

Comment: Please, share a piece of code with us!

Comment: Can you share a piece of code showing how u did this?